# Colorir linha no datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando utilizar o seguinte método:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dgvRequisicao.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            valor = Convert.ToDouble(dgvRequisicao.Rows[i].Cells["valor"].Value);

            if (valor > 20000.01 && valor < 100000)
                dgvRequisicao.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            else if (valor > 100000.01)
                dgvRequisicao.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Mas não está colorindo de jeito nenhum.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar usar o evento [`CellFormating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx).

```
private void dgvRequisicao_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    valor = Convert.ToDouble((string)e.Value);

    if (valor > 20000.01 && valor < 100000)
        dgvRequisicao.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    else if (valor > 100000.01)
        dgvRequisicao.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: funciona.. mas demora mt pra carregar tudo